# "Connect to outlook" needs to be removed !

Tags: 2007

We have a requirement to remove the menu “Connect To Outlook ”  from the “Actions” . If anyone has come across such requirement please guide me on this.
i dont wanna do it via DefaultTemplates.ascx coz it will be effected across server.

Comment: Please help !! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Toolbar Manager from here: http://features.codeplex.com/releases/view/2502

It gives you granular control of all of the SharePoint Toolbar per list.

Answer (score 0):

The ideal solution would be to disable it using a SharePoint Feature with a [HideCustomAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms414790.aspx) element. But I tried this a few years back with no luck - hiding this action was not possible this way. We ended up patching the core.js file to get rid of it. But beware that this is an ugly work-around that service packs and CU's might overwrite again. I have not tried the HideCustomAction with SP2 - maybe it is possible now to do it right?